# return lambda by rvalue ref?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

template <typename... Args>
std::function<void(Args...)> pushToEventLoop(std::function<void(Args...)> && p_function)
{
    auto func = [p_function](Args... args) ->void
    {
        // This is what i would do here, but requires too much source code
        //ThreadPool::enque(std::bind(p_function, args...));
        // This is what i'll do for the sake of the example.
        p_function(args...);
    };
    return func;
}

int main() 
{
    auto function(pushToEventLoop(std::function<void(char const *)>(std::bind(std::printf, std::placeholders::_1))));

    auto function2 = std::bind(function, "Hello World!\n");

    function2();

    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible and how, to return the "func" variable by rvalue ref?

I have a feeling that this is somehow totally insane, but I'd like to know why, so I can restore my sanity.

I have no idea if i have done something horribly wrong. Please provide feedback.

I built this thing so that I can make callbacks that are actually just posted to the treadpool for processing, without the caller or the target knowing anything about this. The middleman that binds them together makes the choice of how to connect them.

https://ideone.com/4Wfhb1

---

EDIT

Ok, so I thought that there is copying going on when I return the func variable. But apparently it's dealt with by RVO, so no copying takes place. I have not verified this, but now that I think about it, that would make sense.

Comment: Why do you think you want to return the lambda variable by rvalue reference? What's wrong with your current approach?

Comment: why do you want rvalue here? I suppose not to eliminate unnecessary copying as it's already eliminated by Return Value Optimisation?

Comment: It is? Nice. I thought the lambda was being copied, but yes, now that I think about it, your statement makes sense. I'll have a google at RVO and see what I can learn.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your question is how to return a lamba in the most eficient way, then just return it by value and use automatic return typ deduction:

```
//this will actually return a lmabda and not a std::function
template <typename... Args>
auto pushToEventLoop(std::function<void(Args...)> && p_function)
{
    return [f = std::move(p_function)](Args... args)
    {           
        f(args...);
    };
}
```

This will leverage RVO and avoid any dynamic memory allocations that `std::function` might have to perform.

Also having an r-value reference parameter usually doesn't gain you anything, if you don't move from it (unless you require that specific interface for another reason). In order to do so here you can leverage c++14's generalized lambda capture (the compiler can't perform that optimization by itself, as `p_function` itself is an l-value).

Now, if your question on the other hand was, if/how you can return a (r- or l-value) reference to a non-static local variable from a function, then the answer is simply:

**NEVER DO THAT!**

Comment: Please add the std::move from the other answer, it's a good change.

Comment: unless you are in a coroutine

Comment: @0xbaadf00d: I agree -added

Comment: @DavidHaim: Can elaborate a bit - and (if it is relevant) what kind of coroutine you mean?

Comment: it will hopefully be standarized in C++17, but a coroutine, AKA resumable function is a function you can stop, return from and return back several time. this has the huge benefit for responsive UI / Webservers scalability. look at Gor Nishanov lectures on CppCon. for example, you can yield a pointer to local variable, do something with it on the caller function, then return to the calee function and continue from there.

Comment: @Yam Marcovic: I was just about to write, that I left the local variable in place to minimize code changes compared to the example, but yes, I'd usually also eliminate it.

Comment: @MikeMB Sure, I just added some random aesthetic improvements as a suggestion.

Comment: @DavidHaim: Ah sorry, I though, you were commenting on the comment by 0xbaadf00d not on my last statement.

Comment: @DavidHaim: I don't know offhand, if the proposed standard coroutines will have a "regular" return type at all, but e.g. in the boost version I believe, there is a difference, between what you return (after completion) and what you yield. This is basically not different from multiple threads: You can e.g. point a global pointer to a local variable in one thread if you know it will stay around long enough, but you wouldn't return a pointer/reference to a local variable

Comment: @MikeMB not true, you can configurate the return type to any type you want as long as it implement couroutine_traits protocole. you can return std::future<T*> for that sense. again, look at Gor lectures, he explicitly demonstrated a case you return a local reference. other than that, courutine is not like a thread. the whole point the function is not destructed if you yield/await from within it. so the local variables are alive

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're trying to do is to move `p_function` into your lambda while avoiding copies? Presumably this is for performance reasons?

In which case you probably want to write it like this:

```
template <typename... Args>

// return by value - because RVO will elide copies for us
std::function<void(Args...)> 

// passing by r-value reference... ok no problem there
pushToEventLoop(std::function<void(Args...)> && p_function)
{
    // but I want to MOVE my p_function into func
    // this will require at least c++1y (c++14)
    auto func = [p_function = std::move(p_function)](Args... args) ->void
    {
        // p_function has now been moved into the lambda ...
    };
    // ... p_function passed to us is now in a valid but undefined state
    // so don't use it here

    // allow RVO to do its thing
    return func;
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about that, but was unsure of how to do it property.